# Alternative to array_minus that expands references in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, diff, array-difference

I have arrays of hash references in Perl. I need to compare them, i.e., effectively do what `array_minus()` does, but I need to do the comparison by the *content* of the hash rather than the reference.

Take this MWE:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Array::Utils qw(:all);
use Data::Dumper;

my %en  = ( 'first' => 'one', 'second' => 'two', 'third' => 'three' );
my %en2 = ( 'first' => 'one', 'second' => 'two', 'third' => 'three' );
my %eo  = ( 'first' => 'unu', 'second' => 'du', 'third' => 'tri' );

my @set = ( \%en, \%eo );
my @subset = ( \%en2 );

print(Dumper(array_minus(@set,@subset)));
```

I believe `array_minus()` compares the references, which are different, so that the output is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'first' => 'one',
          'second' => 'two',
          'third' => 'three'
        };
$VAR2 = {
          'first' => 'unu',
          'second' => 'du',
          'third' => 'tri'
        };
```

Is there an alternative, or an option that would do the comparison by the content of the hashes? Of course when the hashes in the MWE are not included by reference, the comparison works right and only one hash is returned.

Comment: Can't you just loop through and compare yourself?

Comment: Of course I can do it myself, but library functions are always better optimized, and written by people who have thought the matter through. So as long as there's one, it's a better way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work (untested):

```
sub serialize {
    use JSON::XS;
    JSON::XS->new->pretty(0)->ascii(1)->canonical(1)->encode($_[0])
}

sub array_minus_deep(\@\@) {
    my ($array,$minus) = @_;

    my %minus = map( ( serialize($_) => 1 ), @$minus );
    grep !$minus{ serialize($_) }, @$array
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does work! I just had to replace `terse` with `relaxed` and invert the logic: `JSON::XS->new->relaxed(0)->ascii(1)->canonical(1)->encode($_[0]);`